# Using login and sign up code from Parse.com and error appears

Tags: parse-platform

I downloaded and run this login and sign up code from Parse.com, it runs perfectly but when I'm trying to login or sign up on the IOS simulator put it is giving me a login error. It is saying OFFLINE ERROR. Can you please help.

Comment: For which OS is this for? iOS, Android ?
Is "OFFLINE ERROR" all of the error message you received?
Have you entered your own Parse.com credentials into the app for the AppID and ClientID?

Answer (score 0):

As you rightly said Phil tries to insert in the meantime AppDelegate.mi your user codes to parse ..

```
[Parse setApplicationId:@"QEQSUOOZbkbCsA619yjJmAT9Z4uYucItE925O3iT"
          clientKey:@"jMef0TBQXZEVYJZDPSzFUBab719FumQLvJaH4YZ9"];
```

You can find them in the "QuickStart" https://parse.com/apps/quickstart

Also check that you have entered all the required framework to parse, can 'happen that someone is forgotten

> 1. AudioToolbox.framework
> 2. CFNetwork.framework
> 3. CoreGraphics.framework
> 4. CoreLocation.framework
> 5. libz.1.1.3.dylib
> 6. MobileCoreServices.framework
> 7. QuartzCore.framework
> 8. Security.framework
> 9. StoreKit.framework
> 10. SystemConfiguration.framework

Yet even the test for which is always located in page Quickstar ... alemno try to understand what the problem is going to the exclusion of factors